# Define a 1 to 1 relation navigation property for lazy loading

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a 1 to 1 relation of

1 box belongs to 1 pair shoes exactly.

- When I load all boxes I do **not** want that all shoes are also lazy loaded.
- When I load all shoes I do **want** that all boxes are also lazy loaded

how do I have to define my navigation/foreign key property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that EF lets you map the FK in an one-to-one relationship is when the FK is declared as a PK too in the dependent end(Check this [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) for more info)

```
//Principal end
public class Shoes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Box Box { get; set; }
}

//Dependent end
public class Box
{
    [Key,ForeignKey("Shoes")]
    public int ShoesId { get; set; }

    public Shoes Shoes { get; set; }

}
```

Now, about the lazy loading behavior, EF have some [requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx) that you must follow if you want to enable lazy loading for your entities and to have the Entity Framework track changes in your classes as the changes occur. If you don't declare a navigation property as `virtual` (like `Shoes` in the `Box` entity), then it will not be lazy loaded due to EF will not create the proxy objects that support change tracking and lazy loading.

Comment: When I remove the Box Box from the Shoes class and load the Box` Shoe object with .Include() do I still need the virtual on the Shoes Box Box property?

Comment: @Elisa, if you're asking me if it's possible create a one to one relationship without a navigation property in one of the ends then the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I totally forgot you sorry.